# Is there a way to change the default thumbnail for Power BI Reports?

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to change the default thumbnail for Power BI Reports (See below screenshot)?

[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the default thumbnail for Power BI Reports. The thumbnail is automatically generated by Power BI based on the first page of the report.

Comment: Okay, that would explain why it was so hard to find info on this. But why is mine showing as a blue round icon then? That is definately not what my first page of the report looks like.